# Netlogo, segregation

Tags: queue, simulation, netlogo

Does anybody know how to segregate in netlogo? I have a program that simulates men and women entering a bathroom and I want the door to check the gender of the one who enters, If it's male, only males will enter and women will wait, once the males are out, females can enter and the logic goes like that, everything else is in place but I don't know how to go about segregating them, Help would be greatly appreciated ! :D

Comment: It'd be great if you were bit more specific about the technical side of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "segregate", Andre? What have you tried?  Does something store the gender and number of those already in the bathroom?

Comment: why is this not a straightforward use of `if`? Along the lines of `if [sex = 1] [enter]`

Comment: Welcome to NetLogo and to Stack Overflow. Can you show us your best effort to write some code in this direction, and explain where you got stuck? If you show us your code, we can make some suggestions as to next steps.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can make is to make two "breeds" called "men" and "women". You can then use the same functions for turtles, and also add two variables man? woman? using turtles-own

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code, you should include:

```css
breed [ men man ]
breed [ women woman ]
```

on your SETUP be sure to "seggregate" as you call it, include code that distributes your turtles in the different groups, such as

```css
to setup
  ca
  crt 100
  ask turtles [ set breed women ] ;; sets the default breed ]
  ask n-of ( 0.5 * count turtles ) turtles [ set breed men ] ;; sets half of turtles to MEN
end
```